# Node.js issue with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I ran `node server.js` in topmost directory of my project:
And this is the error which I got:

```
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
The magic happens on port 8080

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [your_database_here:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ajay/Desktop/easy-node-authentication-facebook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:549:74)
    at emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ajay/Desktop/easy-node-authentication-facebook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ajay/Desktop/easy-node-authentication-facebook/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:533:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:833:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I've installed `mongodb` and when I open `localhost:27017` in browser, it says `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`. Where is the exact mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use 'mongoose' to connect with mongodb from node. Here is the sample code to do this.

```js
var mongoose=require('mongoose'),
    db = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.connect(db);

//and your code goes here
```

You have to install node module 'mongoose'. Read the docs of [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/).